# Debug.keystore file missing. How to update my app?

Tags: android, publishing, updating, android-keystore

My previous colleague has uploaded an app in GOOGLE PLAY , which is live now.

But now i have to update the application

I am not able to upgrade the new version of the app - It is saying the Certificate is not matching etc.,.

- I came to know that the initial debug file has not been preserved & it has been deleted due to a system format on Windows.

Please provide any ways to update the app .

Thank you